# MarkLogic - Search via Max/Min Filter

Tags: xquery, marklogic, marklogic-8

i want to search documents in MarkLogic.

My documents look like:

```
<product xmlns="myns/products">
  <id>3114</id>
  <materialNo xml:lang="en">1.1160</materialNo>
  <steelName xml:lang="en">SWRCH24K</steelName>
  <name xml:lang="en">wire, wire rod for cold heading</name>
  <chemicalProperties>
    <chemicalProperty>
      <element>c</element>
      <min>0.1900</min>
      <max>0.2500</max>
    </chemicalProperty>
    <chemicalProperty>
      <element>si</element>
      <min>0.1000</min>
      <max>0.3500</max>
    </chemicalProperty>
    <chemicalProperty>
      <element>mn</element>
      <min>1.3500</min>
      <max>1.6500</max>
    </chemicalProperty>
    <chemicalProperty>
      <element>p</element>
      <max>0.0300</max>
    </chemicalProperty>
  </chemicalProperties>
</product>
```

So i want to search via max/min values of the chemical properties. To do so i use this xquery search (simple example):

```
cts:search(/, cts:and-query(
  (cts:collection-query("test"),
   cts:element-value-query(
     fn:QName("myns/products", "name"),
     "wire, wire rod for cold heading"),
   cts:element-query(
     fn:QName("myns/products", "chemicalProperty"),
     cts:and-query(
       (cts:element-value-query(
          fn:QName("myns/products", "element"), "c"),
        cts:or-query(
          (cts:element-range-query(
             fn:QName("myns/products", "max"), "<=", 0.2),
           cts:and-not-query(
             cts:element-range-query(
               fn:QName("myns/products", "min"), "<=", 0.2),
             cts:element-value-query(
               fn:QName("myns/products", "max"), "*")))),
        cts:or-query(
          (cts:element-range-query(
             fn:QName("myns/products", "min"), ">=", 0.1),
           cts:and-not-query(
             cts:element-range-query(
               fn:QName("myns/products", "max"), ">=", 0.1),
             cts:element-value-query(
               fn:QName("myns/products", "min"), "*"))))))))))
```

The problem is that the query above will return the sample document. 
The sub-queries (and-not) are there to check if max/min exists. In some cases there could be only min or only max value.

**But this document is out of bounds?!**

My database does have element range indexes on min and max. All other settings are defaults.

What is the problem? Any suggestions.

***UPDATE***

Ok, thanks for the suggestions but no. Enabling value position do not solve the problem. However a workaround is to remove the "and-not-query" and replace it with an "and-query" and to add new attributes to the documents:

```
<chemicalProperty hasMin="0" hasMax="1">...
```

indexing and querying those attributes works and returns the correct results.

Comment: If you have a follow up question, please post it as a separate SO question. If this question is relevant, then you can link to it in the new one.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that because of your index settings, `cts:element-query` returns true if the `min` and `max` queries match in **any** `<chemicalProperty>` in the same document, not constrained to a single `<chemicalProperty>`. I would only expect to see this in an unfiltered search, however, and I don't see that option in your call to `cts:search`.

First try enabling `element value positions`, which should allow the database to exclude matches from different elements using indexes.

An alternative solution is to use `cts:near-query` to constrain the values in the element query by position.

Comment: Positions should resolve this. cts:near-query needs those too, or it will effectively behave like a cts:and-query. At least, when running unfiltered..

Comment: @grtjn I think `cts:near-query` needs different position indexes than `cts:element-query`? But yes, and I'm a little confused about the apparent filtered query in the question. Given the behavior, I think the safest assumption for now is that OP left it out of the example by accident.

Comment: You are correct, `cts:near-query` requires different position indexes. http://docs.marklogic.com/cts:near-query says: `The word positions index will speed the performance of queries that use cts:near-query. The element word positions index will speed the performance of element-queries that use cts:near-query.`

Comment: What about using path indexes? Would that improve performance over element value positions?

Comment: @HarryBakken I think if `range value positions` were enabled for the path index, that might be faster than `element-value-query` with `element value positions` enabled, since the range index will be memory mapped.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that you are trying to use wildcards in the `cts:element-value-query` calls, but not declaring them wildcarded. Since nothing will match the literal "*", the `cts:and-not-query` does the opposite of what you intend.

You want something like this:

`cts:element-value-query(
    fn:QName("myns/products", "max"), "*", "wildcarded")`

[cts:element-value-query](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:element-value-query)

Alternatively, you could enable one of the wildcard indexes, and ML will detect wildcard queries automatically.

> If neither "wildcarded" nor "unwildcarded" is present, the database configuration and $text determine wildcarding. If the database has any wildcard indexes enabled ("three character searches", "two character searches", "one character searches", or "trailing wildcard searches") and if $text contains either of the wildcard characters '?' or '*', it specifies "wildcarded". Otherwise it specifies "unwildcarded".

Comment: It's typically not necessary to declare the wildcard option. If any wildcard indexes are enabled, the `wildcarded`option will be implicit when there is a wildcard character in the query string.

Comment: I assumed from "all other settings are default" that none of the wildcard indexes were enabled.